# Better method to perform numerical integration on acceleration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have a set of acceleration data points read from the sensor.

I also have the time at which the reading was taken.

How do I numerically integrate to find the instantaneous velocity?

I have tried the following which does give me the result but the I am wondering whether there is a better more accurate method.

```
v_1=v_0+a*dt
```

Where dt is calculated from the difference between the times at which the data was measured.

And by iterating the above I could find the instantaneous velocity.

Comment: The trapezoidal integration method or the Simpson method, in their cumulative variants, might give you better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a number of discrete data points, it is reasonable to assume that the acceleration changes linearly between the data points, i.e.,

[image]

When integrating this function, the midpoint rule is completely accurate. (Midpoint is typically better than trapezoidal btw.)

You can get more fancy assuming that the acceleration is continuously differentiable in which case you'd have to construct a quadratic polynomial in each intersection and integrating that, resulting in [*Simpson's rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule).

Comment: I have an issue in that the acceleration data contains noise. In such cases is it best to use perhaps some alternative way to measure the velocity and position directly? 

Also, do you know any good way to filter out the noise?

Comment: Well, that's a different issue of course. I'd probably Fourier-transform the function, cut off the high frequencies and transform back.

Comment: "Trapezoidal is never better than midpoint" . . . except for periodic data. I don't recommend forgetting about it forever!

Comment: @user14717 Interesting! Seems I was too fast with my judgement. Here's a link for anyone interested: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/12/02/three-surprises-with-the-trapezoid-rule/

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: My comment was somewhat beside the point for this question though! Great answer.

Comment: Well, I did a Fourier transform and the results were terrible. The output is negligibly small